# One way rod bushing design?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Look at the 2 illustrations. I want the rog (fiberglass to only move one way)   Id love to hear some ideas. The bracket is aluminum and yes I can modify, re-design, etc...but need a simple solution that will work in a wet dirty environment (thing wet sand)

[image: Rod thru bracket]

Comment: what 2 illustrations?

Answer (score 1):

Use a spring-loaded split cone or tapered bush (parallel on the inside to  match the rod and tapered into a matching housing), the spring pushes the cone into the housing opposite to the direction of travel.

When the rod moves it pushes the split cone against the spring which allows tsplit cone to spread apart enough to allow the rod to move.